# How do I mirror lists?

Tags: list

Please bear in mind that I am not a native speaker.
I am trying to mirror a list.
For example, I have:

`abc = 1
def = 2
ghi = 3`

I want it to become

`1 = abc
2 = def 
3 = ghi`

Doing it manually is not an option, since it contain 2000+ elements. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you specify more information? Knowing what language are you using would end up with more specific answers.

Comment: I plan on creating a script for IDA Pro. 
My list is this format: Name = Address
I need my list to be this format: Address = Name.
So I can create my script with these functions: MakeName(Address, Name);

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention any programming language, and say that doing it "manually" is possible but you chose to not do it this way because it's time consuming.

I assume it's a one time task. I usually use vim for this :

`%s/\(.*\) = \(.*\)/\2 = \1`

does the trick.